# Embedding Google+ Hangout several rooms to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-api, google-plus

Hello I have a question you think is very difficult to make Google Hangout interactive and dynamic real-time (I mean that unknown people can create their own public rooms infinitely whenever and other unknown persons can enter wing it in random mode free) on the wordpress platform saying the internet would be more fun

know I try but I do not understand how the dynamics of: https://www.verbling.com/community

Is there any way to embed a Google+ hangout app in a PHP-based website? Can I load the app inside an iframe without having to land on Google+ hangout page? If so, how?

any advice to help me an explanation something?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is available here

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/

It have all the sample code and workflow to develop and maintain the hangout app.

Specifically sample apps: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/sample-apps

For Hangout buttons: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you can't embed a Hangout inside an iframe. You can, however, launch a Hangout Video Chat in a new window from your website using the [Hangout Button](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button).